# VueJS display large amount of data

Tags: performance, vue.js, html-table

Right now we are facing problems with our choice of JavaScript framework (VueJS). In our own internal project Dilly-Dally we are facing problems with outputting a larger JSON Object. (aprox. 15000 lines of json)

Our plan was to have this data in a table, however it seems VueJS are struggling a bit with displaying so much information fast.

We tried to replace input fields with just normal text fields to see if that improved performance, and we tried pagination which didn't resolve our problem either.

As it is now we have there is loading time around 20 seconds where your browsers is under full load.

So now dear stack overflow, we turn to you! Do you have any ideas to improve load times?

Here is a snippet of how we make our tables.

```
<b-table striped hover :items="filtered" :fields="columns">
          <template slot="top-row">
            <td v-for="(obj, index) in filter" v-bind:key="index">
              <template v-if="isDatetime(obj[0])">
                <vue-timepicker v-model="filters[index]"></vue-timepicker>
              </template>
              <template v-else>
                <multiselect
                  class="selects"
                  :select-label="''"
                  v-model="filters[index]"
                  :options="obj"
                  :multiple="true"
                ></multiselect>
              </template>
            </td>
          </template>
          <template v-for="field in editableFields" v-slot:[tableCell(field.key)]="{ item, index }">
            <b-form-input
              v-model="item[field.key]"
              v-bind:key="field.key"
              v-bind:class="{changed : regValues[index][field.key] !== item[field.key]}"
            />
          </template>
        </b-table>
```

Comment: if this works but just takes a long time you might want to consider codereview SE

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look into that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Data is Massive, In this case I would just recommend some tips that can improve the performance and more user-friendly experience.
I recommend you to use a loader.
The idea is to load the page and the components first and then fetch the JSON data.

For example:
Set Data state in your parent component

```
data() {
  return {
   isLoading: true,
   data: null
  }
}
```

Add a loader icon to template:

```
<img v-if="isLoading" src="/loader.gif">
```

Then use `Axios` package for example to fetch Json data from the Vue component

```
axios.get('/get-big-json-data')
.then(response => {
  this.data = response.data
  this.isLoading = true
})
```

Add the child component that is responsible for rendering the data.

```
<child-component v-if="data" v-show="!isLoading" :data="data" @loaded="() => isLoading = true"/>
```

Inside the child component call the parent and say that is ready for showing:

```
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$emit('loaded');
  })
}
```